# assign database value as selected value in a drop down box

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populating a dynamic drop down menu from a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456571/populating-a-dynamic-drop-down-menu-from-a-mysql-database)

my form successfully updates mysql database but when the user logs back in I want to assign database value as selected value in a drop down box to what the user has selected before which does not work.

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require_once("config.php"); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   header('Location: login.php'); /
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){         
     $sql = "UPDATE user SET attendance1 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance1']) . "' WHERE username = '" .  mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  
   $sql = "UPDATE user SET food1 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['food1']) . "' WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  
   $sql = "UPDATE user SET drink1 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drink1']) . "' WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  

   header("Location: thanks.html", true, 303);
}
   $row2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" .       mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
     $result = mysql_query($row2) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());
     $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo $row3['shade1']; 
      ?>
```

FORM:

```
<form>

             <input name="attendance1" type="radio" id="Yes" value="Yes" checked="checked"/>Yes
             <br />
    <input name="attendance1" type="radio" id="No" value="No" />No
           </h3></td>
           <td>
                  <select name="colour1" id="colour1" >
               <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
               <option>Red</option>
               <option>White</option>
               <option>Green</option>
             </select>
           </td>
           <td><h3>
                     <select name="shade1" id="shade1" >
               <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
               <option value="Light" <?php if($row2['shade1']=="Light") { echo "selected"; }?>>Light</option>
               <option value="Heavy" <?php if($row2['shade1']=="Heavy") { echo "selected"; }?>>Heavy</option>
             </select>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td><label>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Submit" />
           </label></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
</form>
```

Comment: are actually running the query somewhere? because in your snippets it seems row2 is just the query string, not a result set row returned from db with mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: thats my problem, can you help me out here?

Comment: Didn't you asked the same question 2 hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456571/populating-a-dynamic-drop-down-menu-from-a-mysql-database

Comment: with no answer, i made it more simplified

Comment: No answer but three people trying to help you in the comments. You can edit the post if you want to make it more simplified.

Comment: well i was trying to help on the other thread, but you go and post again, so i wont bother anymore.

Comment: @guido Can you check the edit i have set a result

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery:

1) Use the `$.ajax` call in `$(document).ready()` to get the values you want

2) Set them like this:

Say your `<select></select>` element has an id of "options", set it's currently selected value like this:

```
$("#options").val(optionToBeSelected);
```

where `optionToBeSelected` is the `value` attribute of the `<option></option>` element you want to become selected.

This code should work for you. 
If anyone sees a major/minor flaw in my answer, please let me know!